# How can I implement draft-js generated html code to my next js app?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, draftjs

I have a web app build using nextJs, in a page I am trying to set html code generated from darftJs using below given code.

```
<div className="mt-8 leading-7" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: sanitize(card?.works) }} ></div>
```

The output should look like [image: this].

Instead the output I am getting is [image: like this]

The darftJs generated code is

`<h2><span style="font-size: 18px;"><strong>How to Use AutoDraw:</strong></span></h2><ol><li>Go to <a href="https://www.autodraw.com/"><ins>https://www.autodraw.com/</ins></a></li><li>Click Start Drawing</li><li>You will get a blank drawing canvas.</li><li><strong>On the left side</strong>, you will find:</li><ol><li><strong>Select Tool:</strong> Use the Select tool to select objects and move them on the canvas</li><li><strong>Auto Draw Tool:</strong> Select the auto-draw tool and draw anything you want with your mouse. Let’s say you want to draw a rectangular. Just move your mouse in a rectangular motion and choose from the AI suggestions that match closely with your drawings. Whatever you want to draw, just draw with your mouse as you would draw with a pencil.</li><li><strong>Draw:</strong> Use this tool for freehand drawing without AI suggestions.</li><li><strong>Type:</strong> Add text to the drawing.</li><li><strong>Fill</strong>: Select the Fill tool and click on any item to change the color.</li><li><strong>Shape:</strong> Add geometrical shapes with the Shape Tool.</li><li><strong>Color</strong>: Choose your favorite color</li><li><strong>Zoom:</strong> Zoom in for perfection and details.</li><li><strong>Undo:</strong> Undo the last edits</li><li><strong>Delete:</strong> Delete selected files.</li></ol></ol><p><span style="font-size: 18px;"><strong>Use Menu Button for:</strong></span></p><ol><li><strong>Start Over:</strong> Erase everything and start with a fresh canvas.</li><li><strong>Download:</strong> Download your art.</li><li><strong>Share:</strong> Share with friends</li><li><strong>How-to:</strong> See how tutorial on how to use Auto Draw</li><li><strong>Shortcuts:</strong> See the keyboard and create art faster.</li><li><strong>Artists:</strong> Discover artworks by talented artists.</li><li><strong>About:</strong> Find relevant information about Autodraw.</li></ol>`

Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Finally I fixed the issue with this: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/7756#discussioncomment-3763443